# Unable to Authorize Hub Environment with JWT

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, dev-hub

I'm getting the following error when attempting to authorize a Hub environment to use Salesforce DX. I've set the variables including the path to the server.key. Also, I'm attempting to authorize from a Linux server.Is this a syntactical error or am I missing something here?

```
export JWT_KEY_FILE=/certificates

sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${CONSUMER_KEY} --username ${HUB_USERNAME} \ --jwtkeyfile ${JWT_KEY_FILE} --setdefaultdevhubusername
```

> Unexpected argument --jwtkeyfile

Comment: Remove the backslash \ that's an escape character to handle a linebreak.

Comment: I removed the backslash and now get another error:  Missing required flag --username

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your absolute path to your JWT_KEY_FILE includes both the path and file name with extension - i.e. export JWT_KEY_FILE=/users/yourname/certificates/server.key

Comment: It needed to execute on one line and also the server.key needed to be specified in the path. Thank you both for your responses! It’s working now.